# Order of proc/pid/maps entries

Tags: android, linux, mmap, dlopen, bionic

So each entry in maps file has **start** and **end** addresses where they were mmap'ed. If a library is dynamically loaded (maybe using dlopen()), would the addresses of previous entries be affected in any way? (of course assuming that pid of the process didn't change).

In other words, before dlopen(), here is a sample entry in maps->

**addr1**-**addr2** r-xp 00000000 08:02 135522  /usr/lib64/lib_sample.so

After dlopen()'ing lib_demo.so, would the values addr1/addr2 for lib_sample.so change?

Specifically, I would like to know the behaviour on Android.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If a library is dynamically loaded (maybe using dlopen()), would the addresses of previous entries be affected in any way?

No.